# Regex match time from "Received" e-mail header

Tags: regex, roundcube, sieve-language

I am trying to match header to set in a filter on roundcube. I have found another question about this and i tried the answers, but it doesn't work.

The regex works when tested in RegExr, but roundcube simply denies to save it.

This is my regex: `\s*(?:Sun|Mon|Tue|Weds|Thu|Fri|Sat),\s*\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+(?:0[12345678]|1[89]|2[0123]):\d\d:\d\d`

Which i found in this answer, adjusted it to my needs: [RegEx to match time in "Received: by" e-mail header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689862/regex-to-match-time-in-received-by-e-mail-header)

It should match times between: `18:00 - 09:00`, which it does.

I am not a regex expert, so is there anyone out there that can help me with this?

Comment: `but roundcube simply denies to save it!` ... what is the exact error output?

Comment: This is the error: https://imgur.com/a/yKPlEIK, it's not really clear what is wrong. Saving goes fine when i just enter some text, but not when i enter this regex.

Answer (score 2):

`(?:` ... `)` is not valid in sieve. `\s`/`\d`/`\w` may not be either.

See: [Sieve Email Filtering: Regular Expression Extension](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-sieve-regex-01), [POSIX ERE spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) and [other sieve documents](http://sieve.info/documents).

Use normal groups and character classes:

```
[:space:]*(Sun|Mon|Tue|Weds|Thu|Fri|Sat),[:space:]*[:digit:]+[:space:]+[:alpha:]+[:space:]+[:digit:]+[:space:]+(0[12345678]|1[89]|2[0123]):[:digit:][:digit:]:[:digit:][:digit:]
```

(I replaced `\w` with `[:alpha:]` but this may not be what you want.)

Also, remember to `require ["regex"];`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to parse Received header by regex, Use `date` extension instead:

```
require "date";
require "relational";

if anyof (
    date :value "lt" "Received" "hour" "09",
    date :value "gt" "Received" "hour" "18"
) {
    # do something
}
```

or

```
require "date";
require "relational";

if anyof (
    currentdate :value "lt" "hour" "09",
    currentdate :value "gt" "hour" "18"
) {
    # do something
}
```

See [rfc5260](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5260#section-5.1), it also mentions weekend.